# if else statement

Tags: shell, ksh, array, case

I have a case statement inside some of the if statement, but after doing the case statement inside the if statement, the loop ends. After the case statement, it is supposed to go to the next value on the array. What's happening is the first value in the array, after passing through the if-statement then case, the script finishes instead of looping to the other values in the array.

```
set -A arrs a b c d

num=`expr ${#arrs[*]} - 1`

for x in `seq 0 $num`
do

var1=`some command here`
var2=`some command here`
var3=`some command here`

if [[ "$var1" == "$var2" && "$var3" == "0" ]]; then

 #do something here

elif [[ "$var1" == "$var2" && "$var3" != "0" ]]; then

 echo "\nContinue?"
 echo "[y/n]:\c"
 read yes_no

 case $yes_no in
 [yY])
   echo "You answer yes."
   echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
break
 ;;
[nN])
   echo "you answered  no"
 exit
;;
*)
  echo "\nTry again"
;;
esac

elif [[ "$var1" != "$var2" && "$var3" == "0" ]]; then

 echo "\nContinue?"
 echo "[y/n]:\c"
 read no_yes

  case $no_yes in
  [yY])
   echo "You answer yes"
   echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
  break
;;
[nN])
   echo "you answered  no"
  exit
 ;;
 *)
    echo "\nTry again"
 ;;
 esac

else
  echo "Do back flip"
exit
fi

done
```

Comment: I unable to run this code. Are you getting syntax errors? It would be better if you give a complete working example. May be replace `some command here` with a real command you are using.

Comment: that is not the exact code i am using. it's just the overview of what i have. its just that after the first element of the array, the code is exiting instead of looping to the next element on the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is clear but you may be interrupting the loop when you are using break and exit

```
set -A arrs a b c d

num=`expr ${#arrs[*]} - 1`

for x in `seq 0 $num`
do

    var1=`some command here`
    var2=`some command here`
    var3=`some command here`

    if [[ "$var1" == "$var2" && "$var3" == "0" ]]
    then

        #do something here

    elif [[ "$var1" == "$var2" && "$var3" != "0" ]]
    then

        echo "\nContinue?"
        echo "[y/n]:\c"
        read yes_no

        case $yes_no in
            [yY])
                echo "You answer yes."
                echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
                break
                ;;
            [nN])
                echo "you answered  no"
                exit
                ;;
            *)
                echo "\nTry again"
                ;;
        esac

    elif [[ "$var1" != "$var2" && "$var3" == "0" ]]
    then

        echo "\nContinue?"
        echo "[y/n]:\c"
        read no_yes

        case $no_yes in
            [yY])
                echo "You answer yes"
                echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
                break
                ;;
            [nN])
                echo "you answered  no"
                exit
                ;;
            *)
                echo "\nTry again"
                ;;
         esac

    else

        echo "Do back flip"
        exit

    fi

done
```

Answer (score 1):

You added `break` in the `yes` statement, so it is exiting the `for-loop` and therefore not finish testing the rest of the array. Just remove `break` from the 'yes' case statement.

I tested with some modifications to your code, and got what I believe are your expected results:

```
#!/bin/sh

arrs=(a b c d)

num=`expr ${#arrs[*]} - 1`

for x in `seq 0 $num`
do

var1=`echo "hi"`
var2=`echo "hi"`
var3=`echo "hi"`

echo "var1 equals: $var1"
echo "var2 equals: $var2"
echo "var3 equals: $var3"


if [[ "$var1" = "$var2" && "$var3" = 0 ]]
then

        #do something here
        echo "First check"

elif [[ "$var1" == "$var2" && "$var3" != 0 ]]
then

         echo "\nContinue?"
         echo "[y/n]:\c"
         read yes_no

         case $yes_no in
         [yY])
           echo "You answer yes."
           echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
         ;;
        [nN])
           echo "you answered  no"
         exit
        ;;
        *)
          echo "\nTry again"
        ;;
        esac

elif [[ "$var1" != "$var2" && "$var3" == 0 ]]
then

         echo "\nContinue?"
         echo "[y/n]:\c"
         read no_yes

          case $no_yes in
          [yY])
           echo "You answer yes"
           echo "Some text that will go to the text file" >> some_text.txt
        ;;
        [nN])
           echo "you answered  no"
          exit
         ;;
         *)
            echo "\nTry again"
         ;;
         esac

else
        echo "Do back flip"
        exit
fi

done
```

#### Output (yes test):

```
[root]# sh test.sh
var1 equals: hi
var2 equals: hi
var3 equals: hi
\nContinue?
[y/n]:\c
y
You answer yes.
var1 equals: hi
var2 equals: hi
var3 equals: hi
\nContinue?
[y/n]:\c
y
You answer yes.
var1 equals: hi
var2 equals: hi
var3 equals: hi
\nContinue?
[y/n]:\c
y
You answer yes.
var1 equals: hi
var2 equals: hi
var3 equals: hi
\nContinue?
[y/n]:\c
y
You answer yes.
```

#### Output (no test):

```
[root]# sh test.sh
var1 equals: hi
var2 equals: hi
var3 equals: hi
\nContinue?
[y/n]:\c
n
you answered  no
```